# Why I have StackOverflow in DFS?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stack-overflow, depth-first-search

I'm trying to implement a DFS algorithm in `c++`. I use it to answer the question: "are two vertexes connected or not?", but something went wrong.

Sometimes the program gives correct answer, sometimes crashes with `0xC00000FD` code. I've google it and know now, that is a **StackOverflow** error.

Here's the code:

```
const int N = 4;                     // The minimal example I've know is a graph with 4 vertexes.
std::vector<int> graph[N];           // Our graph
int start = 0;                       // The start vertex
int finish = N - 1;                  // The finish vertex

bool dfs(int old, int v) {           // The DFS function
    if (v == finish)
        return true;
    bool ans = false;
    for (int u : graph[v]) {
        if (u != old)
            ans |= dfs(v, u);
    }
    return ans;
}

void init_graph_ok() {               // With this graph all works fine
    graph[0] = { 1 };               
    graph[1] = { 2 };                // 0 (st) -- 1 -- 2 -- 3 (fin)
    graph[2] = { 3 };
    graph[3] = {};
}
void init_graph_bad() {              // With this graph I have StackOverflow
    graph[0] = { 1, 2 };
    graph[1] = { 2, 0 };             // 0 (st) -- 1 -- 2 -- 3 (fin)
    graph[2] = { 0, 3 };             // ^--------------^
    graph[3] = {};
}

int main() {
    init_graph_bad();
//  init_graph_ok();
    std::cout << dfs(-1, 0);
}
```

Comment: usually this is caused by an infinite recursive call... step through your code with a debugger and see what happens.

Comment: Even if you just let it run in your debugger, it'll probably stop at the point the error occurs so you can inspect everything.

Comment: Your code cannot handle cycles is graph.

Comment: All recursive algorithms suffer from one flaw: even if it doesn't cause infinite recursion, given sufficiently large dataset, it will, eventually, overflow the stack.

Comment: `ans |= dfs(v, u);` looks sus.  A bitwise operator on a bool.

Comment: Your "bad grapgh" is cyclic 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 0 so your dfs will never end ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your code is visiting a particular node more than once, because of which your code runs into an infinite recursion.

Because of the infinite recursive calls, the stack memory gets filled up completely and finally results into a stack overflow error.

**Solution:** Allow every node to be visited almost once by using a `visited` array as follows:

```
const int N = 4;                     // The minimal example I've know is a graph with 4 vertexes.
std::vector<int> graph[N];           // Our graph
int start = 0;                       // The start vertex
int finish = N - 1;                  // The finish vertex

bool visited[N+1];

bool dfs(int old, int v) {           // The DFS function

    if(visited[v]){
        return true;
    }
    visited[v] = true;
    
    if (v == finish)
        return true;
        
    bool ans = false;
    
    for (int u : graph[v]) {
        if (u != old)
            ans |= dfs(v, u);
    }
    
    return ans;
}

void init_graph_ok() {               // With this graph all works fine
    graph[0] = { 1 };               
    graph[1] = { 2 };                // 0 (st) -- 1 -- 2 -- 3 (fin)
    graph[2] = { 3 };
    graph[3] = {};
}
void init_graph_bad() {              // With this graph I have StackOverflow
    graph[0] = { 1, 2 };
    graph[1] = { 2, 0 };             // 0 (st) -- 1 -- 2 -- 3 (fin)
    graph[2] = { 0, 3 };             // ^--------------^
    graph[3] = {};
    memset(visited, false, N+1);
}

int main() {
    init_graph_bad();
//  init_graph_ok();
    std::cout << dfs(-1, 0);
}
```

**PS:** Do not worry about **cycles**, as this logic will take care of cycles as well.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand

Comment: @ДмитрийКлёпов Recursion is not a good idea unless you can guarantee the maximum distance is reasonably logarithmic w.r.t to the number of vertices.